# wordpress function wp_link_pages not working

Tags: wordpress, pagination

The function wp_link_pages() is not working at all in my wordpress template. I have tried all possibilities to make it work. I didn't get any satisfying help for the same online. Please do help me. Guide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the plugin WP-PageNavi - sample code below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

 <!-- Start Loop -->
 <?php query_posts('category_name='SomeCategoryName'&orderby=title&order=ASC&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>           

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php //Loop Code Here ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p class="error">No results found.</p>
    <?php endif; ?> 

   <!-- Start Pagination - WP-PageNavi -->
   <div id="pagination">
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
   </div>
   <!-- End Pagination -->

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<!-- End Loop -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you a ton dciso. It made my job more than easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<!--nextpage-->` for work `wp_link_pages` function.

This tutorial will be help to understand how to work `<!--nextpage-->`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGFjVx9jDd4

Example: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages#Default_Usage

Answer (score 0):

I think header section
the_post(); missing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).