# Add page numbers to post on wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, post, pagination, divide

I am building custom theme. If I have got long post (like review, tutorial) I would like to cut this post for 5 parts. I would love to make navigation at the bottom of post. So, I have added this code to post, but it does not show navigation:

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

So, I have added this in the place of single.php, but it also does not show this:

```
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
```

How to add this element?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269036/wordpress-function-wp-link-pages-not-working

Comment: I will give it try, but is there any way to make it without plugin?

Comment: I used this: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin 
but it also does not show anything.

Comment: How many posts do you have?

Comment: I want 10 posts on main page BUT I do not want to pagination on index. I want to have pagination on single.php to cut every longer post on parts.

Comment: Yes but how many posts you have now? because in pagination  you have to pass certain limit to display post for single page

Comment: I do not understand. I have got 10 posts on website. Also, I divided one news by <!--nextpage--> on 8 parts...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. It is very simple...

```
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
```

Shoud be in the loop...